# SQL Selecting rows and excluding children

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables A and B. A is the parent of B.
I'm trying to find all As which do not have a specific B as a child.
Ordinarily I would do

```
SELECT A.id FROM A 
    WHERE A.id NOT IN 
        (SELECT B.AId FROM B WHERE B.someFK = foo);
```

However for performance reasons I'm keen not to use an inner select.
I've tried something like:

```
SELECT A.id FROM A 
    LEFT JOIN B ON (A.id = B.AId)
    WHERE B.someFK != foo OR B.someFK IS NULL
```

The problem is this returns As which have more than one child regardless of if they have the specified B.

EDIT:
Changed B.id to B.someFK

Comment: Whoops, didn't think it would make a difference to the example but B.id should be B.someFK. Meaning that As can share the foo being excluded.

Comment: you should probably edit that directly in to the question so it's more noticable to new readers.

Comment: you are new to StackOverflow. Please accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with the exists clause, since it was made for such a purpose:

```
SELECT A.id FROM A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE B.id = foo and B.AId=a.id);
```

In most databases it's far more performant than the `in` clause (which basically is an array to compare against) for large record sets.

Aggregations are also expensive, so using an `exists` statement is the way to go imho. You might try aggregations for your scenario, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your `LEFT JOIN` will return one row for each `A`-`B` link (or one row for an `A` with no link to `B`), and then removes the links that fail to match your criteria - leaving behind every other link that a particular `A` has in `B`, which is not what you want.

However, I think an inner select is necessary.
But maybe try an `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT A.id
FROM A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.AId = A.id AND B.someFK = foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a MAX constraint on your parent table. I have not used MySql in a while, but this should give you the idea

```
SELECT A.id, MAX(B.AId) FROM A 
    LEFT JOIN B ON (A.id = B.AId)
    WHERE B.id != foo OR B.id IS NULL
GROUP BY A.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.id FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON (A.id = B.AId)
WHERE B.id != foo OR B.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the entire criteria in the LEFT JOIN.

As far as the duplicate rows are concerned, just DISTINCT it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.id 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B 
ON A.id = B.AId AND B.someFK = "foo"
WHERE B.AId IS NULL
```